# HC-05 + Android ( Wrong echos / data )

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino

So I am facing a problem from a while now . Any suggestion would be good.
First I used my code to receive data from arduino , then I used the bluetoothChat and changed the uuid , I can pair , everything is good , but if I send an entire string from arduino to android I get only parts of that string.
If I use bluetooth terminal from google play everything is ok, and on the description it says it is made from the bluetooth Chat sample .

Code  Arduino

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial mySerial(10, 9); //RX,TX

 long int i = 0;

void setup(){
  mySerial.begin(9600);

}

void loop(){
  mySerial.print("This is a message n. ");
  mySerial.println(i);
  i++;
  delay(100);
}
```

Android code : Bluetooth Chat Sample

Exemple of message received on Android:

Message to be sent!

So first messages I think are waiting while the module is paired .
because every time I get .

```
is is a message n. 466
This is a message n.467
.
. ( here I get correct messages )
.
This is a message n.470
message n. 495
.
.
and after the first messages I get messages like
ssage n.534
t
essage n.m
essage n.
535

( I neved again get an entire message )
```

Handler :

```
h = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
        case RECIEVE_MESSAGE:                                                   // if receive massage
            byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
            String strIncom = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);                 // create string from bytes array              
            sb.append(strIncom);                                                // append string
            int endOfLineIndex = sb.indexOf("\r\n");                            // determine the end-of-line
            if (endOfLineIndex > 0) {                                            // if end-of-line,
                String sbprint = sb.substring(0, endOfLineIndex);               // extract string
                sb.delete(0, sb.length());                                      // and clear

                Log.d("Arduino", "Mesaj:"+ sbprint.toString());



            }
            Log.d("Arduino", "...Mesaj:"+ sb.toString() +  " Byte:" + msg.arg1 + "...");
            break;
        }
    };
};
```

Listener to InputStream

```
  public void run() {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[256];  // buffer store for the stream
        int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

        // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
        while (true) {
            try {
                // Read from the InputStream
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);        // Get number of bytes and message in "buffer"
                h.obtainMessage(RECIEVE_MESSAGE, bytes, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();     // Send to message queue Handler


            } catch (IOException e) {
                break;
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

note you are using a software emulation of serial port, hence timing is not as good as it would be with a hardware UART.

It is likely one or both of the following two possible issues:

1) the start and stop bit are not properly timed, causing back to back bytes. Which occur when a string is set, rather then pecking in keys one at a time.
The solution would be to space out each key.

2) baud rates do not match with in tolerance. Either SLOWING DOWN or SPEEDING UP the baud rate on both the HC05 and Arduino will better match the timing.

I would also recommend ensuring your library is SoftwareSerial, states that it is **NewSoftSerial**. It has many issues fixed. It was implemented in to the Arduino IDE 1.0.+ core libraries, so if you have recent IDE you should have it.

Comment: I got Arduino 1.0.5 so I should have the new SoftwareSerial, can you give me more details how to do the first solution , I will port on my first post the handler where I receive and extract the bytes.